# Installation stops with cmd.exe window on Laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation

I am installing W7 Ent on an LG R580.

I am working with a valid ISO (installs perfect on other systems).

During the installation, before the installation window, the process hangs, and I get a black, cmd.exe screen with the following:

```
Select Administrator: X:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

with a prompt for: X:\windows\system32
```

My keyboard at that time only prints capital letters with '^' before each.

[image]

Only thing that I am able to do is reboot.

In the bios, I tried to disable USB Legacy ( thinking the problem is with my DVD ) - did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Check your keyboard. Maybe you have a stuck key.

Comment: I tried with an external USB keyboard - same results

Comment: what happened if you close this windows with mouse?

Comment: System restarts

Comment: any chance for bios update?

Answer (score 1):

^X in the terminal usually means that the control key is being held. 
x:\ is the ramdrive that the installation OS is being loaded to, so somthing is definitely off if you are seeing prompts to it.

Try a memory scan with the MS RAM diagnostic tool on the windows disk, and make sure win7 likes your ram (I've had a few boxes that had install issues until I replaced the ram; Win7 seems more picky about ram sticks that other OSs; these all ran vista and ubuntu fine).

Comment: Thanks - Windows Memory Diagnostics - passed successfully INVC/LRAND/Stride/WMATS/WINVC - all ok